# Opencl atomic_add() function returns wrong value

Tags: c++, c, opencl, atomic, data-race

I have a problem in OpenCL 1.2.
Look, i have an array as `__global` in the kernel and the group size is 1000.
The problem is that the `atomic_add()` function doesn't work correctly.

My kernel code is :

```
__kernel void kernelfunction(__global uint32_t* buffer){

buffer[3] = 100;

atomic_add(&buffer[3], 1);

...

}
```

If I create 1000 threads, I expect the value of `buffer[3]` will be 1100, am i right?
but the behavior of the program is undefined.
sometime it will be 1100, sometimes 1064, sometimes 1093 and ...

What I have tried:

I also enable the opencl extension like below :

`#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_global_int32_base_atomics : enable`

but the problem is still exists.
in the another project I'd create a simple opencl project and the `atomic_add` works correctly, and I've checked almost the entire of project configuration but i don't know the problem where is.

can you help me?
thanks

Comment: Your kernel code is correct and your problem is likely lies somewhere. Like how are you creating buffer and how are you reading and writing from and to it? Please post a full working example and add details about your OpenCL platform.

Answer (score 6):

Without atomics, a simple access has a race condition when done onto a same element and even worse, all data could have been cached per compute unit and not be updated until kernel ends.

```
buffer[3] = 100;
```

this is undefined behaviour. The result could even be 101;

Even threads in same local group can't have true data without a synchronization command.

Initialization should be made by host because gpu runs threads concurrently. Not serially, excluding atomics. Or, you initialize for its own group (not visible from other groups) and add a `barrier(CLK_GLOBAL_MEM_FENCE)` after that so other threads in same group can see it right.

Comment: Yeah you're right and thanks, but sometimes i need to change (initialize) the element 3 of the buffer in the OpenCL kernel and to prevent the bank conflict i've behavioured like this :   if (id == 0)buffer[3] = 100;      but altough the problem is still exist. what do i do now dear huseyin ?

Comment: after that if sentence, add a barrier. but this would work only for that workgroup. for global threads, you need to initialize in cpu host program